# Best domain registration setup

Tags: networking, domain-name

What would be the best way to go about getting a domain name for a home server behind a DSL modem and router, hosting IMAP email, ftp, Jabber IM, web, and calDav? Also, how would I go about setting up domain prefixes (e.g. imap.maximus419.net, ftp.maximus419.net, etc.) and linking those to specific ports on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a domain registrar which allows you to alter the DNS settings (I suspect most do now). Then, ensure you have a static IP (so your server is at one IP location) and point the A records to it within the domain registrar configuration page / control panel.

Domain prefixes are called SubDomains, these are configured with the registrar typically. They work the same way as an A record.

There are security risks with this, you'll need to configure your server and open ports, set your firewall etc

Comment: Is there a way to use a server without having to get a static address?

Comment: @Fearless Not as far as I know. However, would you explain what (why) you are trying to achieve as there may be other ways.

Comment: Just get my server online for outside access by domain and subdomain name.  E.g. website at www.maximus419.net, ldap directory at ldap.maximus419.net, etc.

Comment: @Fearless why does it have you to be your home server?

Comment: Dynamic DNS solves the non-static address issue. http://freedns.afraid.org is my current preference (Dyn went downhill, IME.) However, offsite hosting is often a better solution than "a server at home", as @DaveRook is implying.

Comment: @Frealess, you may want to consider a VPS

Comment: @DaveRook I want to use my home server first of all for security, and second because I want to learn how to setup/configure a standalone server (this is probably going to be part of my career).  Besides, VPSs seem to be rather pricy.